# monitor bandwidth on interface with tc or iptables

Tags: iptables, tc

I would like to log a warning message to `/var/log/messages` file if either ingress or egress bandwidth on `eth0` interface is over a certain threshold. I could do this with a script which reads the value of `/sys/devices/virtual/net/eth0/statistics/[rt]x_bytes` file, stores the value, sleeps a second, reads those very same values again, calculates the amount of bits per second sent, compares the result with certain threshold and if higher, writes a message to `/var/log/messages` file. However, is there a smarter method? I mean for example with `iptables` or `tc` which could create a log message in case certain bandwidth threshold on interface is exceeded?

Comment: I haven't used it myself but I don't think `iptables -m limit` actually imposes limits by itself. I think it's just used for matching traffic according to rate. You may try to use it with `-j LOG` to see if it lets the activity happen and it just logs to syslog.

Comment: Are you open to averaging solutions like [`sysstat`/`sa`/`sar`](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/)?

Comment: @Bratchley IMHO this can not be achieved with `iptables` `limit` module. `limit` module seems to be suitable for logging relatively infrequent events. For example `iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 1 -j LOG` would log all the ingress ICMP messages up to 1 log entry per second, i.e. even if more than one ICMP message per second is received, only one is logged. In a nutshell, `iptables -m limit` does not seem to be a correct tool for this. @Ulrich Schwarz as much as I tested with `sar`, it simply seems to parse `/proc` so this gives no additional value.

Comment: @Martin that was my main suggestion but looking at the man pages, it looks like there's a a "fuzzy logic controller" with a `--lower-limit` option that would allow you to `-j LOG` if traffic gets above a certain PPS. That would likely create a large volume of logs thereafter, though. It might put you in the right direction.

Comment: @Bratchley Thanks for this suggestion! However, `fuzzy` counts packets in second(pps) not bits in second(bps) and as I have packets with variable length, then this would not work for me. In addition, the way `fuzzy` module operates is not quite what I need- for example even if I could specify `--lower-limit 1Mbps` and `--upper-limit 10Mbps` and traffic is bit over 1Mbps, then only few of the 1Mbps violations are logged. If traffic peaks to 10Mbps, then almost all the violations are logged. `fuzzy` module seems to be for (D)DOS mitigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution which I was looking for. `Iptables` has `rateest` module which does exactly that. For example:

```
# collects all ingress traffic to RATEEST target
iptables -A INPUT -j RATEEST --rateest-name RE1 --rateest-interval 500.0ms --rateest-ewmalog 1s
# creates a log entry(jumps to LOG target) if rate is greater than 10Mbps
iptables -A INPUT -m rateest --rateest RE1 --rateest-gt --rateest-bps 10Mbps -j LOG --log-prefix "Ingress bandwidth >10Mbps "
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `vnstat` with -tr option, then compare with threshold and write log if exceeded.

```
-tr time  
 Calculate how much traffic goes through the selected interface during the giventimeseconds. Thetimewill be 5 seconds if a number parameter isn't included.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -i
```

Just for starters. Look at the headers for RX-OK and TX-OK. Set this up with cron and that's it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Mar 2015
# Get bytes transmitted and received on eth0 and log msg.
echo " "
bytein=`netstat -i | grep eth0 | awk '{print $4 }'`
byteout=`netstat -i | grep eth0 | awk '{print $8 }'`
total=$((${bytein} + ${byteout}))
# echo "IN=$bytein, OUT=$byteout, TOTAL=$total"
max=1000000
outfile=/var/log/messages
msg="Bandwidth has exceeded $max bytes"
if [ $total -gt $max ]; then
    echo "$msg" >> $outfile
    echo $msg
fi
```

What's the big picture OP? I could see doing this for different users to limit their bandwidth, by why do this for the eth0 interface?

Comment: They're aware of how to get the information through a script, they're asking for a more standard and automatic way of doing it using common OS mechanisms rather than something they made themselves.

Comment: @Bratchley, it's using common OS mechanisms (kernel packet/byte counters) and it's not a particularly complicated script. That's a good use of the tools available. IMO, of course.

Comment: @roaima As **Bratchley** already mentioned, I would like to avoid scripts for this task as I need to keep those running in background in an endless loop. To be honest, I was fairly sure that such functionality is built into NetFilter or at least extensible with NetFilter modules. @user77853 `eth0` interface is dedicated for one VPN tunnel. However, as I mentioned in my initial post/question, I'm not looking for a script to log a warning message if either ingress or egress bandwidth on interface is over a certain threshold.